# Date-specific hats - Timezone specific?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2012

Do date-specific hats (such as "'Tis The Season") respect a user's timezone?  I'm guessing not since the only region specific info in the profile is the Location field

Comment: UTC... always UTC.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well the Stack Exchange knows  your IP.

They know when your awake.

They know when you've been bad or good.

So be good for...

Wait I went a little of topic there...

All of the time based events on the Stack Exchange are usually **based on UTC Time**.

Comment: Interesting - I could have sworn that I'd seen some behaviour that suggested otherwise (votes today, for example).  I may have imagined it, though.

Comment: I can confirm that Amanaplan is right :)

Comment: @Aarthi you really know when we are sleeping?!

Comment: "Last visited: 6 hours ago" We can make educated guesses. :P

Comment: @Aarthi - can you set a reminder to wake me at 7:30 tomorrow, please?  I have a plane to catch. ;)

Comment: Accepted for being the first accurate answer, as well as for making me laugh - the obvious criteria for accepting an answer in my book. :)

Answer (score 3):

Most Stack Exchange events are based on UTC/Zulu time, just for consistency and convenience.

For this event, there *are* safeguards in place to account for timezone changes and spans. Don't worry -- as long as you meet the criteria, your hat *should* be awarded to you.

Comment: I'm not too worried - I'm unlikely to be posting on Christmas Day anyway, but I was curious.  Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: Incidentally, shouldn't "'Tis The Season" take a leading apostrophe since it is a contraction of "It Is"?  Nitpicky, I know. :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen, all dates happen in UTC; for example, the rep cap is for one day from midnight to midnight UTC. So I'm guessing that the day specific hats would work that way as well.